# XOAuth2 gmail for client ID, Client Secret and Refresh Token for node mailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, gmail-api, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer with NodeJS server. I have created following with one of my email address earlier. 
client ID 
client Secret 
refresh Token

I am facing problem as google has change ways to configuration  for it's XOAuth2. 
Any help from guys who have recently configured will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-Gmail clients, Gmail supports the standard IMAP and SMTP protocols.  The Gmail [IMAP and SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview#top_of_page) servers have been extended to support authorization with the use of standard **Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL)**, via the native IMAP AUTHENTICATE and SMTP AUTH commands, to authenticate users.

> As long as the libraries used support the Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL), they should be compatible with the SASL XOAUTH2 mechanism supported by Gmail.

It is further detailed in [SASL XOAUTH2 Mechanism](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#the_sasl_xoauth2_mechanism) how to send OAuth 2.0 access tokens to the server such as initial client response using the following format:

```
base64("user=" {User} "^Aauth=Bearer " {Access Token} "^A^A")
```

[Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) documentation will really be helpful  for you too.

Comment: Thank you for giving reset to my searches. I have gone through the Nodemailer docs and it's implemented now :)

Comment: Glad to know that. :)